# Don't understand this recursion function

Tags: c, function, recursion

This is a recursive function from a book i read, since it's not a loop there this function prints those out puts which more like it's looping.
I have tried to understand how this function `up_and_down` work.

In the book i read it say that a recursive function call it self but the in code i can't see it directly how?

can some one please explain this for step for step what is going on in the function thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void up_and_down(int);
int main(void){
  up_and_down(1);
  return 0;

}
void up_and_down(int n){

  printf("Level %d: n location %p\n" , n , &n);
  if(n < 4){

    up_and_down(n+1);
  }
  printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n",n,&n);
}
```

output

> Level 1: n location 0x7ffd8988c9fc
>
> Level 2: n location 0x7ffd8988c9dc
>
> Level 3: n location 0x7ffd8988c9bc
>
> Level 4: n location 0x7ffd8988c99c
>
> LEVEL 4: n location 0x7ffd8988c99c
>
> LEVEL 3: n location 0x7ffd8988c9bc
>
> LEVEL 2: n location 0x7ffd8988c9dc
>
> LEVEL 1: n location 0x7ffd8988c9fc

Comment: Isn't there a call to `up_and_down(n + 1) inside `up_and_down`?

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes it is but still i can't see it through how that work

Comment: **Roughly** to call a function: `CALL` an address (= save _somewhere_ where you are and then continue execution on that address). When function ends then `RET` (= read where you were from _somewhere_ and continue execution there). I'd suppose that this has been covered just few pages before in your book. Don't worry, go back and re-read!

Comment: A piece and paper and a pencil are most helpful here. And executing your program step by step with a debugger is also helpful here. Learning how to use a debugger will be helpful in the future as well.

Comment: Step through the code line-by-line using a debugger.

Comment: Step through the code line-by-line using a debugger - seconded.  You will learn MUCH more running the code for yourself than asking for explanations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the recursive function is called a new context is created and *piled up* on top of the last context. This context is stored on the stack.

At the moment of entering `up_and_down()` for the first time (i.e.: `up_and_down(1)`) you have the following context:

```
-----------
| LEVEL 1 |
-----------
```

The rectangle above represents the context inside of the call `up_and_down(1)`.

The second time this function is recursively called (i.e.: `up_and_down(2)` ), the context is:

```
-----------
| LEVEL 2 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 1 |
-----------
```

For the third call (i.e.: `up_and_down(3)`):

```
-----------
| LEVEL 3 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 2 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 1 |
-----------
```

And so on until `n` is equal to *4* (i.e.: `up_and_down(4)`):

```
-----------
| LEVEL 4 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 3 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 2 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 1 |
-----------
```

The `if` statement in the function `up_and_down()` is evaluated to false for the first time when `n` is equal to *4*.
Therefore it won't occur any additional recursive call (i.e.: the call `up_and_down(5)` never takes place).
For that reason `n == 4` is said to be *the exit condition* for this recursive function.

The execution flow continues with the second `printf()` (i.e.: `LEVEL 4` is displayed). Then the context of the fourth call is destroyed:

```
-----------
| LEVEL 3 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 2 |
-----------
-----------
| LEVEL 1 |
-----------
```

The control flow is the one returning from the call `up_and_down(4)`, that is, in the recursive function with the context created by the call `up_and_down(3)` (i.e.: `LEVEL 3` is this time displayed).

All the following steps occur analogously.

Comment: kudos for the diagrams. Must have been tedious, but should help OP understand stuff much better

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void up_and_down(int);
int main(void){
  up_and_down(1);
  return 0;

}
void up_and_down(int n){

  printf("Level %d: n location %p\n" , n , &n);
  if(n < 4){

    up_and_down(n+1); // HERE : the function calls itself
  }
  printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n",n,&n);
}
```

the function is called in the main with the an integer as parameter. When it's called from the main n = 1. then it runs the function (up_and_down), prints the level and the location a first time.

n value is 1 and 1 < 4. Then it matches the condition and the function calls itself using n + 1 as parameter; it will run the function again but with n = 2.

it will do it until n reachs 4
and then the function execution will continue calling the rest of the function (the second printf)

as you can see up_and_down is called IN up_and_down function

Comment: is it so that the `main` call it only once then the function call it self by puting the new `n` as argument ??

Comment: why the main call it if it call it self?

Comment: @user7738839 yes exactly. The function is called a first time in main and then it's called directly from the function itself with a new argument

Comment: @user7738839 your main function is the heart of your software. if you do nothing in your main nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void up_and_down(int);
int main(void){
  up_and_down(1);  --> Step 1
  return 0;

}
void up_and_down(int n){

  printf("Level %d: n location %p\n" , n , &n);  --> step 2
  if(n < 4){             /* --> step3 checks if n is less than 4 */

    up_and_down(n+1);   /*--> step 4(if step3 is true) when if condition true this is executed */
  }
  printf("LEVEL %d: n location %p\n",n,&n); /* step5 irrespective of the if condition value of n is printed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you are standing infront of a door which leads to a room. The room also has a door inside which leads to the next room and so on.

Also imagine you are holding a pencil and a piece of paper which contains instructions for you to do:

> Step 1: Enter the next room.
>
> Step 2: Draw a cross onto the piece of paper.
>
> Step 3: Count all crosses and shout out loud: "I have ENTERED room number [count of crosses]".
>
> Step 4.1: If you counted less than or equal 4 crosses, go to Step 1.
>
> Step 4.2: If you counted 4 or more crosses, go to Step 5.
>
> Step 5: Leave the room.
>
> Step 6: Erase one cross from the piece of paper.
>
> Step 7: Count all crosses and shout out loud: "I have LEFT room number [count of crosses]" and go to step 5.

You are finished with the task when you reach the start again.